# Javascript: how to make a website that allow user to scroll in any direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

This site is pretty cool, http://pharrellwilliams.com/, and I'm wondering what function makes the users can scroll in any direction and the size of page is endless.

Comment: probably some html, javascript and css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is no really suited to this site. I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn more about how to ask quiestions that are better suited to this site.

Comment: Probably not any given function.  While the scrolling anywhere could be achieved with HTML & CSS alone, the "endless" aspect of it could be accomplished with some Javascript lazy-loading.

For this particular page, though, if you pop open the Chrome developer tools the first thing you see is a link to [PixiJS](http://www.pixijs.com/) -- I suspect that that is the main engine driving this particular experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the library that the website uses:

http://www.pixijs.com/

https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js

It shows you when you open up the inspector and take a look at the console.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, make a div that's HUGE, like 10,000px (hardcoded!) in width or something that's way bigger than any possible screen size, and however high you need it to be. Then, fill with content. Boom! Your done.